# Can I use Apache Camel with Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut

We have been evaluating the Micronaut framework and are looking to use the Apache Camel library. I do not see a specific integration with Apache Camel. The Apache Camel library does support a set of annotations.

**Questions**

- Can we use Apache Camel with Micronaut?
- If we attempt to use Apache Camel annotations, will it work but revert to using the Java annotation api, i.e. work but not be optimized for Micronaut?

Comment: Have you able to run Apache Camel and Micronaut? Any example link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we use Apache Camel with Micronaut?

Yes.

> If we attempt to use Apache Camel annotations, will it work but revert
>   to using the Java annotation api, i.e. work but not be optimized for
>   Micronaut?

Yes.